# Мало у нас с ней забот было

Tags: синтаксис

> Мало у нас с ней забот было.

Если я правильно понимаю это независимое предложение. К сожалению мне не знакома эта конструкция. Можно сказать, что это "сокращенное" предложение от придаточного сравнения? "*Как будто мало у нас с ней забот было*."?

Answer (score 2):

**Мало у нас с ней забот было.**

Другие варианты: *Как будто мало у нас с ней забот было. Можно подумать, что мало у нас с ней забот было.*

У этих трех предложений разная грамматика, но смысл одинаковый. В них утверждается противоположное тому, что соответствует действительности. **На самом деле забот было много.**

Такой художественный прием называется **ирония или антифразис**, он относится к теме "Выразительные средства языка".

Пример:

**Ну спасибо, удружил ты мне (= сделал что-то неприятное).**

Прямое значение:

УДРУЖИТЬ,  Разг. Оказать дружескую услугу, сделать кому-л. что-л. приятное, нужное, полезное.

**О грамматике предложения:**

*МАло у нас с ней //забОт было.*

Безличное предложение (количественно-бытийный тип).  Было мало забот – сказуемое. У нас с ней – дополнения.

В предложении использована **инверсия** (перестановка членов предложения) для обеспечения логического выделения слов с помощью ударения.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

*Мало у нас с ней забот было*

Нет, это не сокращённое предложение, но разговорное - точно.  О его стилистической особенности  уже сказали, а теперь о грамматике. Во-первых, здесь есть инверсия. Прямой порядок был бы таким: Забот у нас с ней было мало. Грамматическая основа - *забот было мало*.

О таких конструкциях Валгина пишет:

> Такие предложения есть основания считать двусоставными, с особой
>   (генитивной) формой одного из главных его членов. Иногда такой генитив
>   прямо и называется подлежащим, а сам тип предложения -
>   генитивно-количественным. Например: Воды в трюмах - 30 сантиметров
>   (Пауст.). Генитивные предложения часто имеют в своем составе прямые
>   (лексические) указания на количественное значение. Эти слова или
>   словосочетания вместе с формой родительного падежа образуют
>   грамматическую основу предложения, причем типовое значение таких
>   предложений «сообщение о количестве названных предметов» передается
>   расчлененно - род. п.+количественное слово или словосочетание.
>   Количественное значение может быть выражено
>   неопределенно-количественными местоименными словами много, мало,
>   немного или существительным в неопределенно-количественном значении:
>   Нас много, мы играем, нам весело (Л. Т.); Мало слов, а горя реченька,
>   горя реченька бездонная (Н.); фразеологизированным сочетанием:
>   Считанное число солнечных дней; наречием: Вдоволь воды; Фонарей
>   видимо-невидимо (Купр.); собирательным числительным: Коренных
>   фронтовиков было шестеро (Сол.) и др.

Место генитивных предложений в системе простого предложения определяется нечетко. Иногда их относят к особым разновидностям безличных предложений, в других случаях - к односоставным подлежащным. Чаще же - они вообще не упоминаются в классификационных рядах, так как не укладываются в привычную схему подлежащных - сказуемостных предложений.

Валгина считает, что безличными их называть неправомерно,

> так как категория безличности непосредственно связана со сказуемостью,
>   а усматривать в форме генитива сказуемое нельзя: эта форма выполняет
>   функцию называния предмета (или предметов) и утверждения его (или их)
>   наличия в большом количестве, следовательно, функционально генитивные
>   предложения ближе к номинативным, нежели к безличным.

Генитив здесь имеет субъектное значение. Такие предложения можно в какой-то степени, хотя бы формально, сблизить лишь с безличными отрицательными типа Ни огня, ни черной хаты (П.); И кругом ни звука (М. Г.); функционально они различны, так как категория отрицания - категория сказуемостного плана, и родительный, появившийся здесь в результате эллипсиса глагола бытия (ср.: Не было ни огня; Нет ни огня), обусловлен глагольной зависимостью, в то время как в генитивных предложениях типа Грибов-то! родительный не может быть объяснен зависимостью от глагола, он вообще не является зависимым словом.

Независимость синтаксической позиции такого генитива приводит некоторых лингвистов к выводу о функциональной близости его с подлежащим.

http://studepedia.org/index.php?post=40665&vol=1